# Get nested value of object with key field

Tags: arrays, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Im using the DataGrid from material-ui to make a table to show my data. The problem I have is that I have a nested array of data, but I can't get the nested value in the datagrid with the
`

```
key field:
const columns = [
{ field: "Patient.full_name", headerName: "Full name patient", width: 130 },
{ field: "id_number", headerName: "id number", type: "number", width: 130 },];



export default function DataTable(props) {
const { exams } = props;


return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGrid rows={exams} columns={columns} />
    </div>
);`
```

id_number works. But I cant seem to get the nested value to show of the full_name, I also tried "full_name", "Patient:full_name". Is there maybe an option to get that value in the string field?

[this is how the data is nested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLY6x.png)

Answer (score -1):

Here,
field: "Patient.full_name" considers this field value as a string.
You need to remove double quotes and make it Patient.full_name.

```
const columns = [
{ field: Patient.full_name, headerName: "Full name patient", width: 130 },
{ field: "id_number", headerName: "id number", type: "number", width: 130 },];
```

Comment: That would attempt to access a Patent variable, which in this case breaks the code.